# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input but the PHP file is fine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to show some data retrieved with php via JSON/Ajax system but I get this error: 
**[object Object] | parsererror | SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input**

My php script is working (I can see the JSON output when I type the php file directory directly on my browser):

```
  "action": "success",
  "message": {
    "statusFin": {
      "txtStatus": "fin"
    },
    "statusCom": {
      "txtStatut": "comm"
    },
    "statusattLiv": {
      "txtStatut": "attLiv"
    },
    "statusLiv": {
      "txtStatut": "Liv"
    },
    "statusFac": {
      "txtStatut": "Fac"
    }
  }
}
```

My script is pretty simple I'm just tryin for now to show a log message:

```
    $.ajax({
          async: false,
          url: DIR_URL + 'ajax/nameOfFile.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {'day': day, 'week': week, 'month': month, 'year': year},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(datta, status){
            console.log('outpuut AJAX : success ');
          },
          error : function(result, status, errorText){
            console.log('outpuut AJAX : ' + result + ' | ' + status + ' | ' + errorText);
          }
        });
```

[EDIT] PHP file:

```
    <?php
$msgErrorJSON = 'und';
$ret = array(
    'action'  => 'erreur',
    'message' => array()
);

$listInfo['statusFin']['txtStatus']         = 'fin';
$listInfo['statusCom']['txtStatut']         = 'comm';
$listInfo['statusattLiv']['txtStatut']      = 'attLiv';
$listInfo['statusLiv']['txtStatut']         = 'Liv';
$listInfo['statusFac']['txtStatut']         = 'Fac';

$ret['action'] = 'success';
$ret['message'] = $listInfo;

$retJSON = json_encode($ret);

echo $retJSON;
```

It always goes to the 'error' case and I get: **[object Object] | parsererror | SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input**

Hope I was clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: It might happen that your server script is return html characters.. usually happens when there's an error

Comment: Can you show us the actual JSON output? Because there's a syntax error in there somewhere.

Comment: Show how you're creating the json. If you're creating the json manually instead of using json_encode, it could be invalid.

Comment: I don't really understand what you said ... I changed datatype to html and it succeeded but I use arrays so ....

Comment: Never ever use `async:false`. It is  horrible practice and is deprecated by browser vendors. You should be seeing warnings about deprecation in your console

Comment: @RiggsFolly done.

Comment: a) use `header("Content-Type: application/json");` in your PHP at some point before the `echo`. b) remove `dataType: "json"` from your ajax call (you don't need it)

Comment: @ChrisG it works, thanks. But I can't seem to access the data inside, how can I do that?

Comment: Start with `console.log(datta)` in your success callback.

Comment: @ChrisG I get nothing, it's empty

Comment: Try this: `$.getJSON(DIR_URL + 'ajax/nameOfFile.php', function (data) { console.log(data); });`

Comment: Still nothing, it doesn't execute the function in there ...

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors? Check the XHR itself? I used to do Shotgun debugging; it's hell. Just check the developer tools instead, and you will be able to fix this in no time.

Comment: There is litterally nothing .... Where should I look? I'm not even sure anymore (thank you so much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't put the answer before because of the 2 days waiting policy (and then I forgot, sorry), so here it is: The problem was with the mapping, I forgot to add the PHP file path in my controller ....
Thanks everyone.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to this line.

```
echo $retJSON;
```

Because $restJSON contains data as a array or may be array with object.
use print_r to print this json.

```
print_r($retJSON);
```